# Refresh only the content panel in master page on page navigation in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, master-pages

I have a master page with Header, Menu, Content and Footer panes in my asp.net mvc (C#) application.

I don't want the Header and Footer panes to refresh on each page navigation, only the Menu and Content panes should get refreshed.

How can i achieve it in the asp.net mvc application? any suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pure ajax load of the inside of the pages could be achieved by capturing link clicks in the navigation to something like:

```
$('a:not(.external)').each(function(){
  $(this).attr('href', '#'+this.href);
});
```

Then you could use the [jQuery BBQ plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/) to manage your back button and page loads with the '[onHashChange](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-bbq/examples/fragment-basic/)' event. This will allow you to ajax load each of the main portions of the page (likely with a `$('#main-div').load(url);` type call). The demo for BBQ does pretty much exactly what you'd like, with the added benefit that you don't ruin the back button, so I would suggest taking a hard look at that.

Answer (score 0):

Make Ajax calls to the controller, like below and create the "*.ascx" PartialView you need

```
    $('#divMainContent').load("./LoadMainContent");



    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult LoadMainContent()
    {
        return PartialView("MainContent", sp);

    }
```